# Associating two objects (each with a class) in an array using pointers

Tags: c++

The goal of my program is to allow the user to enter up to 100 names for people and 100 names for cars. Then the user can "register" a car to as many people as s/he wishes using pointers. I know I need a person class and a car class and I need to use two arrays of size 100 for each. But I am completely lost on how to set anything else up. I have done a *lot* of researching to try and figure something out. I would be extremely appreciative if anyone could give me some basic example code for how something like this could be done.

I don't have much code:

```
class Person{
public:
    person();
    Car* in_car;
};

class Car{
public:
    Car();
};

int main()
{
    Car cars[101];
    Person people[101];
}
```

Comment: Paste the code maybe help more.

Comment: start cr eating the objects and use data structures for associations

Comment: Could you be more specific as to how to use data structures for association?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a vector of car pointers to the People class.

```
class People{
...

private:

vector<Car*> _pointer;
};
```

Comment: The code I'm creating now will be used in part of a larger project where it will be necessary to have used an array

Comment: It is probably better to use a `std::set` for tracking the association, this would avoid duplicate registration.

Comment: No problem you can substitute vector for array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399001/how-to-manage-an-array-of-pointers-to-objects